# What you get after completing Human Laboratory World?

Tags: mario-forever

I am playing Mario Forever. And know how to get to human laboratory but I am not getting past of it, but that's not my question. What we get after completing human laboratory level? Any special powerups or extra live?

Comment: It's unclear what specific game you are referring to and what exactly your question is.  There was no PC version of Super Mario Bros. If, as I suspect, the game you are playing is Mario Forever, please edit your question to show such. As for the question itself, are you asking what levels/world come after human laboratory, or what rewards you get for beating it?

Comment: @Fambida Oh ok, sorry edited